# Server.Execute Duplicates Dynamic Content

Tags: loops, dynamic, asp-classic, duplicates

I created a page in ASP that loads dynamic content  with code similar to this:

```
<%
  var1 = int(rnd * 5) + 1
  var2 = int(rnd * 10) + 1
%>
<html>
<body>

what variable 1 is: <%=var1%>
what variable 2 is: <%=var2%>

</body>
</html>
```

Then I have another page that uses Server.Execute to execute the previous file mentioned 2+ times using a loop. The code looks like this:

```
<% filename = request.querystring("page") %>

<table class="domtable">
<% for j = 1 to 2%> <%qnumb = qnumb + 1%>
  <tr> 
      <td align="left">
        <%server.execute (filename)%> 
        <% If qnumb < 2 then%>
        <br/><hr><br/>
        <%end if%>
      </td></tr>
  <%next%>
</table>
```

So for the last couple of months this has been working perfectly for me, loading different numbers for both variables on the two separate executions. Then today, I duplicated a folder on my server, renamed it and now magically, the variables are the same number about 9 out of 10 times the browser is refreshed.

This happened to me with the same files on my second server a month ago, and I had to delete all the files off of the second server, and download them from my first server (the one duplicating now), then upload them back and that fixed it. Unfortunately, I didn't download the entire server contents of my first server so I'm unable to reverse the process. So I'm not sure if this issue is server-side, or if it's related with the code I'm writing? I just don't know why it would work for so long then just stop working out of nowhere.

I've tried using meta no-cache controls. I deleted the new folder I duplicated earlier from the server and that didn't work. I also tried deleting files from the last couple days that have been uploaded and that didn't work either. I've tried loading 'filename' as an array such as:

```
filename(1) = request.querystring("page")
filename(2) = request.querystring("page") 

for j = 1 to 2
  Server.Execute(filename(j))

next
```

I really hope someone knows what I'm doing wrong here.

-EDIT-

I'm also doing this and getting the same results.

```
<%
'rnd.asp'
pStr = "private, no-cache, must-revalidate" 
Response.ExpiresAbsolute = #2000-01-01# 
Response.AddHeader "pragma", "no-cache" 
Response.AddHeader "cache-control", pStr
server.execute ("rndj.asp")
response.write ("<hr>")
randomize(3)
server.execute ("rndj.asp")
%>

<%
'rndj.asp'
pStr = "private, no-cache, must-revalidate" 
Response.ExpiresAbsolute = #2000-01-01# 
Response.AddHeader "pragma", "no-cache" 
Response.AddHeader "cache-control", pStr
randomize
response.write rnd
response.write "<br>"
response.write rnd
%>
```

I started to use this code below which looks at the specified file as plain text and removes the asp tags from it then uses Execute to run it within the original file. The problem with this is all my pages that i call use  in them for other resources and the replace script wont let me add asp tags around the include lines.

```
<%
Dim sTargetFile, sTargetFileContents
Dim oFSO, sContents

Function GetFileContentsForExecution(sTargetFile)

'Obtain a reference to the FileSystemObject
Set oFSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Obtain the file contents
sContents = oFSO.OpenTextFile(Server.MapPath(".") & "\" & sTargetFile).ReadAll
Set oFSO = Nothing 'reference to the FileSystemObject

'Remove the ASP scripting tags
rand = int(rnd * 2) 
sContents = Replace (sContents, "<" & "%", "")
sContents = Replace (sContents, "%" & ">", "")
GetFileContentsForExecution = sContents
End Function

sTargetFile = "rndj.asp"

for j = 1 to 6

'Get the contents of the file to execute
sTargetFileContents = GetFileContentsForExecution(sTargetFile)
Execute sTargetFileContents

next

if j < 3 then 
response.write ("<br/><hr><br/>")
end if
%>
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using Includes instead of Server.Execute? I think you could easily eliminate this problem by changing your files to be includes instead.

Comment: Yea, I started out using includes but the list of files I would need to include is way too huge and slows down the load time of the page drastically. I found using Server.Execute was way faster and gave me the ability to use a variable within the script since you can't use variables inside of an include tag.

Comment: It works on one server but not the other. Both using the exact same scripting, and both hosted by Godaddy.

Comment: Its not clear to me a) what it is you expect to happen and b) what you are actually getting.  Can you include in the question the results you are getting and an example of the results you would expect?

Comment: the current result i am getting is after using server.execute to execute the same file (twice) the random variables are the same, so the first instance of the page execution would display something like "77" and then the second instance of the page execution will display the same "77".

What is supposed to happen, and now what only happens on 1 out of 4 of my servers. Is the first instance of the page execution might read a number like "77" and the second instance of the execution would read another number like "15".

you can see what I mean here: http://stevenschemers.com/random/rnd.asp

Comment: Using Server.Execute to execute multiple instances of the same file (showing different outputs) has worked perfectly on my two major servers until just yesterday. I'm so confused why everything would be working fine then out of nowhere it doesnt :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Link to working solution](http://stevenschemers.com/random/rnd.asp)

```
<%
 'rnd.asp'
 randomize

 application("randomseed") = rnd
 server.execute ("rndj.asp")

 application("randomseed") = rnd
 server.execute ("rndj.asp")

%>

<%
 'rndj.asp'
 randomize application("randomseed")
 response.write rnd
 response.write("<br />")
 response.write rnd
 response.write("<br />")
 response.write("<br />")
```

%>